# How to Include Multiple Splash Screen Resolution Images in Windows Store Apps

Tags: microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

How do you include multiple resolutions of splash screen images in Windows Store apps? I have looked through the documentation, but I'm not able to find anything in providing different screen resolution images.

Answer (score 1):

Doh, just was finally able to find the pages that describe including multiple resource files. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781198.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465262.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx

Long story short, you need to name the files with the given scale factory:

...\test.scale-100.jpg
   \test.scale-140.jpg
   \test.scale-180.jpg

The splash screen resolutions are:

100%: 620x300
 
140%: 868x420
 
180%: 1116x540